# How do I overwrite a single line in a .dat file without overwriting the whole file? C++

Tags: c++, file-processing

I'm new to C++, so I'm not sure what is allowed and what isn't. At the while loop, I'm trying to read each line in the file individually and when it gets to the line that corresponds to the record # provided by the user (1-100), that whole line will be replaced with the record, name, quantity, and cost that was input by the user. However, I don't want to overwrite the whole file, because the user should be able to input another item afterwards and previous one should remain. I know the for loop is probably dumb, but I was trying weird stuff. I've heard about seekp and seekg, but I rather not use classes in this unless I can still use seekp and seekg and without classes.

There are 100 records in the file formatted similarly to this minus the underscores (record number, tool name, quantity, cost):

0_____none_____0_____0.00

I hope this is enough info. I've been struggling on this for quite a while.

```
void addItem(fstream& add)
{
    int record = 0;
    string toolName = "none";
    int quantity = 0;
    double cost = 0.00;

    int rec = 0;
    string tool = "none";
    int qty = 0;
    double cst = 0.0;

    cout << "\nEnter the record number (1-100) : ";
    cin >> record;
    cout << "Enter the name of the tool: ";
    cin >> toolName;
    cout << "Enter the quantity of the tool: ";
    cin >> quantity;
    cout << "Enter the cost of the tool: ";
    cin >> cost;


    while (add >> rec >> tool >> qty >> cst)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (rec != 0) { //if existing rec# is not equal to zero, keep the line the same 
                add << setw(6) << rec << setw(14) << tool << setw(10) 
                    << qty << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << fixed << cst << '\n';
            }
            if (rec == record) { //if existing rec# is equal to user input, change line to user input
                add << setw(6) << record << setw(14) << toolName << setw(10) 
                    << quantity << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << fixed << cost << '\n';
            }
            if (i == record) {//if line equals the value of the user input, change line to user input
                add << setw(6) << record << setw(14) << toolName << setw(10) 
                    << quantity << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << fixed << cost << '\n';
            }
            else { //keep any other records as default
                add << setw(6) << 0 << setw(14) << "none" << setw(10) 
                    << 0 << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << fixed << 0.00 << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nYou have added a new record.\n";
}
```

Comment: You cannot just read and write the same stream like this. You have to have two streams, one that reads the file, and one that creates a new file, but the above is basically the correct approach, processing one line at a time, but you just have to have two different streams, and you create a new file for the second stream, and at the end your new file replaces the existing file. Mission accomplished. Wasn't that easy?

Comment: Even if you could open the file for reading and writing and somehow find the record you want to replace, is it ALWAYS exactly the same length?  What happens when the text or the record becomes bigger than the one you are replacing?  Or will that never happen?

Comment: If you are sure the records are ALWAYS all the same length then here is a sample where it reads until it finds a specific record and then replaces that record with a new one: https://onlinegdb.com/r1enYQmhDI

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I assume you mean ifstream and ofstream? I was using fstream since I've heard it has the properties of both the other streams. I'm curious about using a second file, but I'm a bit confused with "at the end your new file replaces the existing file." Replaces it how exactly? Would you mind elaborating? Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The records that are input by the user are unlikely to ever be the same as the items will have different names, quantity, and cost.

Comment: If the replacement can be longer than the original record then you will overwrite the start of the next record unless you rewrite the entire file.

Comment: Just because fstream inherits from both ifstream and ofstream (loosely speaking) doesn't mean both can be used at the same time, any more than you can drive a car in both forward and reverse gear, simultaneously. And as far as replacing a file, have you ever heard of "renaming a file"? Create a new file and rename it to the original file's name, replacing the original file. Again: mission accomplished, wasn't that easy?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would like it to be that easy, but it wont let me replace the original file with the new one. I get an error saying "permission denied" or "file exists". What do you think could be done?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Feel free to post a new question to stackoverflow.com, but only after making sure that it meets all requirements for a [mre].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Never mind I got it! Thanks for your suggestion with the second file. If it wasn't for you, I'd still be stuck on this and probably never would have figured it out! Thank you so much :)